# Showing .rtf , .txt or .pdf files in web view of android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have three different kind of files ,

1. Document file
2. text file
3. pdf file .

while clicking button i need to render those file in webview of android, is it possible or not.

If any one know the solution means help me out.

Note: i need load those files from asset folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to display files in a `WebView` or could you work with the standard [`ACTION_VIEW` Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)?

Comment: i need to show it in web view only....this is my requirement,..

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible or not.

You can display a text file in a `WebView` via the `text/plain` MIME type. `WebView` cannot render PDF. I have no idea what you think a "document file" is.

Comment: i'm sure by "document file" he meant ".doc" file.